# How to insert picture through textbox using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
package modules;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class PostUpdating {
    public void Execute()
    {
        WebElement w = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("whats-new"));
        w.sendKeys("/C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
        Select sel = new Select(LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("rtSelectPrivacy")));
        sel.selectByVisibleText("Public");
        Select sel1 = new Select(LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("whats-new-post-in")));
        sel1.selectByVisibleText("My Profile");
        LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("aw-whats-new-submit")).click();
    }
}
```

**The html**

```
<div id="whats-new-textarea" style="position: relative;">
<textarea id="whats-new" class="bp-suggestions linkBox" rows="10" cols="50" name="whats-new" style="display: inline-block; height: 50px;"></textarea>
<div id="rtm-drop-files-title">Drop files here</div>
<div class="rtmp-url-scrapper-container">
<img class="rtmp-url-scrapper-loading" src="http://demo.rtcamp.com/rtmedia/wp-content/plugins/buddypress-media/app/assets/admin/img/boxspinner.gif">
<table id="rtmp-url-scrapper" style="display: none;">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table id="rtmp-url-scrapper-img-holder">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td style="height:100px; overflow:hidden;" colspan="2">
                     <div id="rtmp-url-scrapper-img">
                        <img src="">
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td id="" style="width:50%; text-align:right;">
                     <input id="rtmp-url-prevPicButton" type="button" value="<">
                  </td>
                  <td id="" style="width:50%; text-align:left;">
                     <input id="rtmp-url-nextPicButton" type="button" value=">">
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                     <div id="rtmp-url-scrapper-img-count"></div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </td>
      <td>
```

I want to insert a image into my text box  but when I use Sendkeys and gave the path from my computer but instead of sending the image it is sending the path only into my text box.Also there is a button in my webpage for uploading the picture but when I clicked on button windows dialoge box open. So selenium can't deal with Windows GUI.So Any help how to do this?

Comment: This code looks proper , Just need 1 change , replace your upload button id with "whats-new" so it will be like `WebElement w = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("your upload button id"));
    w.sendKeys("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");`

Comment: Not working..... may be my Display:Inline-block is this the issue

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting an error from the validation "Please add some content to upload the file"

Comment: That is not selenium error:)

Comment: yes I know. but why this error is occurred because in no data is going in text box. That means there is something to change in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
drv.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert an image into the text box you need to send the filename along with the absolute path as a *character sequence* to the element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("textarea.bp-suggestions.linkBox#whats-new"))).sendKeys("/C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='bp-suggestions linkBox' and @id='whats-new']"))).sendKeys("/C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
  ```