# How to select the auto suggestion from the dynamic dropdown using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, autosuggest

I am trying to select the value for **Subjects** field in the following form: https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

It is an input field that dynamically gives suggestions based on our input and later we need to select values from those suggestions. I am unable to select the desired value.

The Below code only populates the input area but the value is not selected.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput")).sendKeys("English");
```

```
driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput")).click(); //This line doesnot click on the desired value.
```

How to Select the desired value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke click on the only *auto suggestion* **English** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#subjectsInput"))).sendKeys("English");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.subjects-auto-complete__menu"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='subjectsInput']"))).sendKeys("English");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'subjects-auto-complete__menu')]"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: toolsqa_subject]

Comment: How to inspect element with class 'subjects-auto-complete__menu' as it hides on click

Comment: Thanks, @DebanjanB. Now I am able to complete it.

Comment: @DebanjanB How did you find 'subjects-auto-complete__menu' class in "//div[contains(@class, 'subjects-auto-complete__menu')]"? When I inspect the web page I dont find this class.

Comment: @RevanthBangera Agree, it was a bit tricky as the div vanishes from the DOM when you try to click on it. But as it is a auto suggestion, the class name always gives a hint that the element with this class will contain the actual auto suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The code below worked for me.

```
    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String url = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form";
    Driver.get(url);
    WebElement products=Driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput"));
    products.sendKeys("English");
    products.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    products.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```