# How to click on a button in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click a button inside a hikvision camera login page using internet explorer ( note that this website only works with IE) with eclipse
this is the code for the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary login-btn" type="button" ng-click="login()"><label class="ng-binding" ng-bind="oLan.login">Login</label></button>
<label class="ng-binding" ng-bind="oLan.login">Login</label>
```

Image:

[image: See this Image]

This is my code , everything works fine but the button won't click.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\SAAD\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_4.0.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://10.67.0.230");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        Username.click();
        Username.sendKeys("admin");
        WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        Password.click();
        Password.sendKeys("ezEqL7?Ss=g");
        WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.className("btn.btn-primary.login-btn"));
        Login.click();
```

Also I have tried this xpath but still don't work

```
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[5]/button"));
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What problems faced?

Comment: since i'm using IE there are no tools to get the xpath for it , so if you can give me the xpath because im not able to get it also i tried locating the button using it's class but nothing happens

Comment: Again, please share your code. After that we possibly will be able to help here

Comment: Code added to the question .

Comment: What is `http://10.67.0.230`? It seems to be some your local address, correct?

Comment: yes it's a local camera on my network , but the page opens fine and my sendkeys also works fine , i just need to click the "Login" button , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.login-btn[ng-click^='login'] > label.ng-binding"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary login-btn' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'login')]/label[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Login']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Still nothing clicks , i tried both lines under  "Password.sendKeys("ezEqL7?Ss=g");"

Comment: What do you mean by _Still nothing clicks_? The code solution is to click on the button element with text as **Login** and have nothing to do with `Username.sendKeys();` or `Password.sendKeys("ezEqL7?Ss=g");` as such.

Comment: I mean the login button is still not pressed .