# How to automate accept cookies pop-up from java app using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The app is going to load the system default browser, load a special website, and then login automatically

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class theurl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://www.playok.com/en/spades/";
    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.browse(new URI(url));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But before trying to login, first the cookies should be accepted automatically; is there a simple way to do it rather than using an external library? if not, which library can do the job

I tried this code, but didnt help:

```
WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String url = "http://www.playok.com/en/spades/";
Driver.get(url);
Driver.findElement(By.id("cookie_action_close_header")).click();
System.out.println("completed");
```

Comment: remember that writing cookies takes some time... the server will send a header that tells the browser to write a cookie.  It doesn't take long, but does take a small amount of time.  If, after you accept the cookie prompt, you don't wait for a little bit before navigating to another page, the choice may not be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  Driver.get("http://www.playok.com/en/spades/");
  new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.ckbut.but0"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  Driver.get("http://www.playok.com/en/spades/");
  new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='ckbut but0' and text()='ACCEPT']"))).click();
  ```