# How to click on a radio button using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, radio-button

I'm trying to click on a radio button in selenium java but it's not clicking.

This is the inspect on the radio button:

```
<input name="timeSyncType" class="radio" id="radioNTP" type="radio" ng-click="oSettingTimeInfo.szTimeMode='NTP'" ng-checked="oSettingTimeInfo.szTimeMode=='NTP'">
```

I tried this

```
WebElement radio =  driver.FindElement(By.id("radioNTP"));
radio.click();
```

also I tried this

```
WebElement rbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP']"));
rbutton.click();
```

but no luck, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs you will have to make sure that this id `radioNTP` is unique in HTMLDOM or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `//input[@id='radioNTP']` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If yes, then there are quite a few ways to perform click in Selenium.

**Code trial 1:**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP']")).click();
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP']"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP']"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

If No, then you will have to change the locator and use the one which represent the desire node.

PS: `Thread.sleep(5);` is just to solve this problem, if any of the above code works, Please replace the web element with `WebDriverWait`.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#radioNTP[name='timeSyncType'][ng-click^='oSettingTimeInfo']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP' and @name='timeSyncType'][starts-with(@ng-click, 'oSettingTimeInfo')]")).click();
  ```

---

However, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so ideally to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#radioNTP[name='timeSyncType'][ng-click^='oSettingTimeInfo']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='radioNTP' and @name='timeSyncType'][starts-with(@ng-click, 'oSettingTimeInfo')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , still it's not working any other ideas ?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you see any error?

Comment: I don't see any error , it's just won't click .