# Can't find web element with Selenium Java within tradingview.com

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait, opera, tradingview-api

I can't access a specific element of a webpage with Selenium in Java.

I need to access the "sign in" option inside of a submenu of the [Trading View webpage](https://www.tradingview.com).

I tried xPath, CSS selector, etc. but nothing works, I guess it's inside some kind of subdivision of the webpage I don't know, but I'm positive it's not an `<iframe>`, I have already checked that. I could be wrong though.

[image: The element I need to access]

My code:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){

      System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver","C:\\Documents\\LIBRARIES\\Opera Driver\\operadriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com");
      driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]"))).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
     // This is where I need to select the element of the webpage, nothing works so far (Xpath, CSS, ID...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the **Sign in** element first you need to click on the *user menu* icon and then you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Open user menu']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[data-name='header-user-menu-sign-in'] div[class^='label'] div[class^='label']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Open user menu']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Sign in']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

All you missing here is a delay / wait.
You need to let page loaded the element you are going to access before accessing it.

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
```

Will not do that.
You need to use Expected Conditions explicit wait here:

```java
WebDriverWait wait;
```

Also you need to improve your locator.
This would work better:

```java
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver","C:\\Documents\\LIBRARIES\\Opera Driver\\operadriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com");
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'user-menu-button--anonymous')]"))).click();

}
```