# Selenium: Clicking on React button

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate testing of my react site for school, the first page loads fine and I enter a password and hit enter to submit, on the second page there are a lot of buttons with the same class name, so the only way to differentiate them is from their text value, such as "logout", "demo test" and others, please take a look at the picture to see the layout and the HTML code, the problem I am having is to actually click through the page using selenium, when just manually clicking it works fine:
I tried using:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("demo test")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[[@type, 'button'] and [text()='demo test']]")).click();
```

and a whole variety of find elements by class name, but they all have the same class name, take a look at the picture.

HTML:

[image: html of site]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **demo test** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn' and text()='demo test']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: geez thanks man, i've been working on this all weekend and couldn't figure it out, you're a life saver!!!!!!!!!