# Selenium Automation: How to find element to send text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to automate a test in Microsoft Redeem Code page

https://account.microsoft.com/billing/redeem

I tried to enter value by below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("tokenString")).sendKeys("GXXFV-CPMKR-VQVFV-2CCFD-J47GZ");
```

Inspect element showing:

```
<input aria-label="Enter 25-character code" name="tokenString" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Enter 25-character code" maxlength="tokenLength" autofocus="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" id="tokenString" class="ember-text-field ember-view">
```

I tried lot of ways nothing worked out , Spent 4 hrs cant figure out please correct my code
Environment:

- Eclipse IDE - Java - Selenium latest
- Mac OS - Chrome

Correct Code to find element.

Comment: <input aria-label="Enter 25-character code" name="tokenString" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Enter 25-character code" maxlength="tokenLength" autofocus="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" id="tokenString" class="ember-text-field ember-view">

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element, so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ember-text-field.ember-view#tokenString[name='tokenString']"))).sendKeys("GXXFV-CPMKR-VQVFV-2CCFD-J47GZ");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ember-text-field ember-view' and @id='tokenString'][@name='tokenString']"))).sendKeys("GXXFV-CPMKR-VQVFV-2CCFD-J47GZ");
  ```

---

### Update

Checkout the following line of code:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ember-text-field.ember-view#tokenString[name='tokenString']"))).sendKeys("GXXFV-CPMKR-VQVFV-2CCFD-J47GZ");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ember-text-field ember-view' and @id='tokenString'][@name='tokenString']"))).sendKeys("GXXFV-CPMKR-VQVFV-2CCFD-J47GZ");
  ```

Comment: i'm using Selenium latest one , The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, long) is deprecated.

Comment: @Dilz Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @undetectec Selenium. Not working Command: [f303bd41063d05b6c69168abb1252859, findElement {using=xpath, value=//input[@class='ember-text-field ember-view' and @id='tokenString'][@name='tokenString']}]