# In Selenium Webdriver using Java should I have to use element.click() before element.SendKeys for input text box?

Tags: selenium

```
driver.get("<url>")
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id(..));
name.click();
name.sendKeys("<input text>");
```

In the above code is it required to have name.click() first , or is it optional as the field is located and it should be able to send the input without having to click on it first

Comment: It depends on the html. From my own experience in some cases `element.sendKeys(String string)` realy does not work without `element.click()`, but in some cases it does. In one project I had to even add `Thread.sleep(100)` after the click.

Comment: Did you try that by yourself? Update the question with your observation with both the cases.

Comment: Thank you . I could not try as Selenium is not working after Chrome driver update. I am going to post this question as a separate post

Answer (score 0):

### `<input>` tag

The [`<input>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) tag specifies an input field where the user can enter data. The *`<input>`* element can be displayed in different ways, depending on the type attribute. As an example:

- *`<input type="text">`*  (default value)
- *`<input type="button">`*
- *`<input type="checkbox">`*
- *`<input type="email">`*
- *`<input type="file">`*
- *`<input type="hidden">`*
- *`<input type="number">`*
- *`<input type="password">`*
- *`<input type="radio">`*
- *`<input type="submit">`*
- *`<input type="url">`*

---

### This usecase

As your usecase involves sending a *character sequence* presumably it should be of the following type:

```
<input type="text">
```

Generally you won't have to invoke [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) before invoking *`sendKeys()`* but ideally to send a character sequence you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("birtviewer"))).sendKeys("Richard Bernard");
```

However, incase the element is a dynamic element having [**onfocus**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onfocus.asp) event attribute which fires the moment that the element gets focus as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onfocus="myFunction(this.id)">
```

you may require the additional step to click within the element.