# Capital letters got rearranged / swapped when using sendKeys() using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, sendkeys

I've faced a problem using Selenium and chromedriver.
When using `sendKeys()` method with capitals, letters are rearranged.
For example, I use:

```
element.sendKeys("ABCD")`
```

but in runtime it sends "CDAB" string.

As far I played with this method, it happens only with CAPITALS.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text based HTML of the element would have been helpful to debug the issue in a better way.

However, it is always recommened that to send a character sequence to any *`<input>`* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) to [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) for the element to ***render*** completely and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector"))).sendKeys("ABCD");
```