# Selenium WebDriver: Unable to locate dynamically changing React InputBase component element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to locate an element with id.
The Developer tools shows this:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Partner name" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="" id="mui-85700">
```

The id always changing every time I reload the page.

I think I find a solution to locate the element:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'mui')]")).click();
```

But now I get the following error:

```
(org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <p id="mui-51640" class="MuiTypography-root MuiTablePagination-caption MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorInherit"> is not clickable at point (1124,747) because another element <div class="MuiDialog-container MuiDialog-scrollPaper"> obscures it
```

How can I solve it?

Side note:
In developer tool I see 4 web elements which contains "mui" String.
On the page I only see 2 web elements: one with `<input id="mui85700"...>` and another one is `<label id="mui85700"...>`
As before I said I need the input id field.

Answer (score 1):

The *`<input>`* element is a [React InputBase component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-base/) and a dynamic element and the trailing dynamic value of the `id` attribute will will get changed everytime you access the application afresh. So you have to construct a dynamic [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver).

---

### Solution

To click on the *`<input>`* element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInput-input.MuiAutocomplete-input.MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd[id^='mui'][placeholder='Partner name']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd' and starts-with(@id, 'mui')][@placeholder='Partner name']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may use findElements and get all the elements form web page
Use a loop and check if the element is visible or element is clickable. This is solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this,

```
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));


            for (int i=0; i<products.size(); i++){


                String name = products.get(i).getText();

                    System.out.println(name);

                if(name.containsAll('text')) {

                    driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath")).get(i).click();
    }
        }
```