# select2 dropdown with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I have a drop down in WordPress products page which is a select2 ajax enabled.

I have managed to show the options in the drop down using selenium.

But i am not able to select one of the options from the list.

I am able to get the element using the below code. But the element is not castable to Select nor clickable.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced']"))
```

Any ideas how to select any option from it?

The HTML code for the drop down is

```html
<tr>
  <td class="attribute_name">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <strong>Brand</strong>
    <input type="hidden" name="attribute_names[0]" value="pa_brand">
    <input type="hidden" name="attribute_position[0]" class="attribute_position" value="0">
  </td>
  <td rowspan="3">
    <label>Value(s):</label>
    <select multiple="" data-placeholder="Select terms" class="multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced" name="attribute_values[0][]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option value="107">Adidas</option>
      <option value="110">Gul Ahmed</option>
      <option value="111">Khadi</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--open" dir="ltr" style="width: auto;">
         <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="-1" aria-owns="select2-attribute_values0-to-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-attribute_values0-to-result-d16b-111">
               <ul class="select2-selection__rendered" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals" aria-atomic="true">
                  <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="text" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Select terms" style="width: 418.797px;" aria-owns="select2-attribute_values0-to-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-attribute_values0-to-result-d16b-111"></li>
               </ul>
            </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
    <button class="button plus select_all_attributes">Select all</button>
    <button class="button minus select_no_attributes">Select none</button>
    <button class="button fr plus add_new_attribute">Add new</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: _But the element is not castable to Select nor clickable_: What error do you see?

Comment: When i call .click() on it i get org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:
When i try to cast to Select i get ClassCastException Cannot cast RemoteWebElement to Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML:

```
<select multiple="" data-placeholder="Select terms" class="multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced" name="attribute_values[0][]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
```

The WebElement is clearly a `<select>` node and to select one of the options from the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select.multiselect.attribute_values.wc-enhanced-select.select2-hidden-accessible.enhanced[data-placeholder='Select terms']")))).selectByVisibleText("Adidas");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced' and @data-placeholder='Select terms']")))).selectByValue("110");
  ```

Comment: I am getting this from your code

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: selec.multiselect.attribute_values.wc-enhanced-select.select2-hidden-accessible.enhanced[data-placeholder='Select terms'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: @Chris There was a typo which I have corrected now. Retest and let me know the status.