# Can't click on Submit button, not working in automation testing, works manually

Tags: java, selenium, button, automation, automated-tests

I have a standard form with 2 text boxes to fill and a submit button. The Submit button suppose to work after filling in the first mandatory text box.
It works manually, but when running on the automation infrastructure, the element doesn't get clicked.
The odd thing is that when debugging, the submit button is not clickable too, although it's not greyed out.
I tried the 3 classic methods:
Javascript:

```
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Actions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

click:

```
element.click()
```

**Not working manually while in automation **
only when closing the form and creating a new one it works.

Comment: is the xpath right? can you add a condition isEnabled() before clicking?

Comment: Used both xpath and css to locate the element. I used the function isEnabled and it returns false. The enabled mode is null. The thing that bugs me the most is why on debugging, when I manually click it doesn’t respond. Also, the step successed, but on screen the form is not being sent

Comment: Have you tried ?     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator))

Comment: Yes I have this by default in my method before executing click command, with different timeout given. Tried 10 it didn't work.

Comment: Check the javascript attached to the submit button. your automation is doing something that is clearly not being detected by the javascript implementation

Comment: Ok, maybe something broken with the button? I will ask the developers

Comment: How are you setting the text input? If you do that in js it might not fire the event it needs to update

Comment: When putting text, the send button becomes available to click. While stopping the automation and trying to click manually it doesn't work. So not Selenium method will help. But if I try manually from the start it works, or if I close the form and open a new form

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in the console while clicking?

Comment: there is no error, it clicked but nothing happened, didn't close the form

Answer (score 1):

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on any ***clickable***  element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following solutions:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//elementXpath"))).click();
```

As an alternative, using `Actions` class:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//elementXpath")))).click().build().perform();
```

Another alternative, using `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//elementXpath"))));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each Selenium method I use fail. The issue here is different and weird, only at automation the button is not clickable.  I tried clicking on it multiple of times but it's not clickable. Manually works perfect. And if I close the form and open a new one it works

Answer (score 0):

According to your steps an replays , may be there is a hidden popup or something block your elements ,so use **WebDriverWait** not only clickable but try to **elementToBeSelected()** , **invisibilityOfTheElementLocated()** or
**presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()**

increase the waiting time to be able to detect the issues