# How to click on Close icon/element on the Facebook sign-up page using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, facebook, xpath, webdriverwait

I am  new to Selenium and learning. On the Facebook sign-up page I want to click on the X as shown in the below screenshot, but I am unable to click it. It's an img element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yC/r/Q0G2UVjVQ4_.png']")).click();
```

[image: check the screenshot]

Comment: The reason why your code is failing is surely due to the image name being changed as well => `Q0G2UVjVQ4_.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an *`<img>`* tag which is the *`preceding-sibling`* of a *`<div>`* tag which is the immediate ancestor of the *`<div>`* tag with text as ***Sign Up***

[image: cross]

---

### Solution

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Sign Up']//ancestor::div[1]//preceding-sibling::img[1]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath `Xpath = //img[@class = '_8idr img']` to click on that icon for your case sample code will look like this
**Note :-** use implicit Wait on driver instance or you can use explicit Wait for this particular element to wait till clickable.

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Create New Account')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class = '_8idr img']")).click(); // To click on the cross icon in sign Up page
```

Comment: _8idr may change any second so that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @wizKid yaa i agree with your concern **-8idr** sounds like a randomly generated class for the current scenario it is constant do depend on session changes or browser.