# How to pass value in search field within Swiggy website using Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to pass value in input field i.e. Search box? I tried using  cssSelector as:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']"));
```

and using className as well.

Snapshot of the element:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the *Search* field within the [Swiggy](https://www.swiggy.com/search) website you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']"))).sendKeys("Pizza");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for restaurants and food']"))).sendKeys("Pizza");
  ```