# Selenium Java - Not able to find element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to access the select element on this page:
https://yt5s.com/en133?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSBjQ9tuuTJQ

I'm using the following code to access the dropdown:

> ```
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control form-control-small hidden']/optgroup[@label='mp3']")).click();
> ```

But I receive the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@class='form-control form-control-small hidden']/optgroup[@label='mp3']"}

The following answers in this chain are all correct. I found the issue to be that my code opened the above url in a new tab and I didn't switch to this new tab yet.
The following piece of code let me switch to the new tab and now it is working.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: remove the class `hidden`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of `optgroups` inside the `Select` we can't use here regular `Selenium` `Select` mechanism.
Your locator is wrong.
Please try this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='formatSelect']//optgroup[@label='mp3']//option[@data-format='mp3']")).click();
```

In case the command above will not work directly try first to open the dropdown by

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='formatSelect']")).click();
```

And then to select the desired option with

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='formatSelect']//optgroup[@label='mp3']//option[@data-format='mp3']")).click();
```

Comment: Apologies for not giving enough issue, I found the error to be because my prior part of the script opened this link in a new tab and I had to switch to a different window. The code you have is correct and working

Answer (score 0):

The desired `<option>` element,

```
<optgroup label="mp3">
    <option data-format="mp3" value="128">128kbps (4.18 MB) </option>
</optgroup>
```

is within it's respective ancestor `<optgroup>`.

---

### Solution

To click select the desired option you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://yt5s.com/en133?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSBjQ9tuuTJQ')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='formatSelect']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='formatSelect']//optgroup[@label='mp3']//option[@data-format='mp3']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: optgroup]

Comment: I ran this bit of code and it still was not able to find it: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='formatSelect']"))).click();

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.