# How to find the below onclick="javascript" element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to write a CSS for the below in selenium:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Fields" onclick="javascript:clearForms()" xpath="1">
```

Code trials:

```
(By.cssSelector("input[value='Clear Fields']")).click();
```

But I'm getting null point exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Fields" onclick="javascript:clearForms()">
```

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='Clear Fields'][onclick*='clearForms']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Clear Fields' and contains(@onclick, 'clearForms')]"))).click();
  ```