# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted error clicking on a radiobutton using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

There are 2 radioboxes "Yes" and "No", the "No" is selected by default and I want to click the "Yes" one but keep getting the same error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="radio" id="si_notificar" name="notificar" value="1" class="custom-control-input notificar"> is not clickable at point (361, 308). Other element would receive the click: <label class="custom-control-label text-sm" for="si_notificar">...</label>
```

I have tried by xpath, by id, using WeDriverWait (I'm using `time.sleep` right now with an extended time just to be sure that the time isn't the problem) but it gives me the same error.

YES radio box:

````
<input type="radio" id="si_notificar" name="notificar" value="1" class="custom-control-input notificar"> ```
````

NO radio box:

```
<input type="radio" id="no_notificar" name="notificar" value="0" class="custom-control-input notificar" checked="">
```

My code:

```
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"si_notificar").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

[ElementClickInterceptedException](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException) occured while clicking on:

```
<input type="radio" id="si_notificar" name="notificar" value="1" class="custom-control-input notificar">
```

as ideally while dealing with *checkbox*, *radiobutton*, etc, instead of targeting the *`<input>`* you need to target the *`<label>`* element preferably using the *`for`* attribute.

---

### Solution

To click on the [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) assiciated with text as ***Yes*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='si_notificar']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='si_notificar']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for='si_notificar']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='si_notificar']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Can you explain why the code in the question didn't work?  I'm curious.

Comment: @JohnGordon Checkout the answer update and let me know if any further questions.

Comment: Still not working, now it gives the error `element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (382, 1307)` (same with CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH)

Comment: Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: check if there are some element above or look for iframes

Comment: @emigoti Glad to be able to help you.