# Selenium click works in Python but not Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I believe I have the same logic in Python and Java, with the same xpath to a button (picture below).

Python code:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tool_form']/div/div[1]/div/button")
button.click()
```

Java code:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tool_form']/div/div[1]/div/button"));
button.click();
```

[image]

The button gets clicked using my Python code, but not my Java code. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: is the page loaded in Java vs. python? What happens if you try to get the text content from the button? (does the Java version still get the content)?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the ***clickable*** element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *Java* client:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='tool_form']/div/div[1]/div/button"))).click();
  ```
- Using _Python_client:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tool_form']/div/div[1]/div/button"))).click()
  ```