# html Element not clickable via Java Selenium "jsExecutor"

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following JS HTML Element:

```
document.querySelector('[value="fixedsumcredit_kp"]')
<input id=​"-0198e3aa-d2b1-46ce-bdf0-192e60662cd3-fixedsumcredit_kp" type=​"radio" name=​"-0198e3aa-d2b1-46ce-bdf0-192e60662cd3" value=​"fixedsumcredit_kp" style=​"height:​ 100%;​ opacity:​ 0;​ position:​ absolute;​ width:​ 100%;​ top:​ 0px;​ left:​ 0px;​ z-index:​ 1;​ cursor:​ pointer;​ -webkit-tap-highlight-color:​ rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)​;​">​
```

I tried to click it via Selenium and jsExecutor as follows:

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='fixedsumcredit_kp']")
    public WebElement oneKlarna_ratenkauf_6;

    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", oneKlarna_ratenkauf_6);
```

and

```
        WebElement oneKlarna = (WebElement) jsExecutor.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"value='fixedsumcredit_kp'\")");

        System.out.println("oneKlarna: " + oneKlarna);

        jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", oneKlarna);
```

First script does not click and second script does not create the JS "WebElement oneKlarna"
The console click on the other hand works fine in chrome developer console:

```
document.querySelector('[value="fixedsumcredit_kp"]').click()
```

My question is: How to click the displayed "input" HTML element in Selenium correctly?

UPDATE:

I have the followin `iframe` around the HTML Element:

```
<iframe id="klarna-klarna-main" name="klarna-klarna-main" title="Klarna" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://js.playground.klarna.com/eu/kp/v1.0.0-23083-g146e667ef2/main.html#data=%7B%22onShowExternalDocumentRegistered%22%3Afalse%2C%22fullscreenIframeID%22%3A%22klarna-klarna-fullscreen%22%2C%22popupWindowEnabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22nativeHookApiSupported%22%3Afalse%2C%22nativeHookApiFeatures%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22paymentMethodCategory%22%3A%22klarna%22%2C%22purchaseCountry%22%3A%22DE%22%2C%22scheme%22%3Atrue%2C%22sessionType%22%3A%22payments%22%2C%22sessionID%22%3A%2270b4ebfe-6ae5-5596-8a24-8ddcd540e0d3%22%2C%22merchantName%22%3A%22Playground%20Demo%20Merchant%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22playground%22%7D&amp;" style="height: 701px; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; min-width: 280px; display: inline;"></iframe>
```

Is the behaviour known to you?

Comment: can you check if there is no iframe in your page?

Comment: Have you tried just using selenium's base `.click()` method?

Comment: `.click()` does not work either.
I will have a look if there is an iframe present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Driver.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
        Driver.getDriver().switchTo().frame("klarna-klarna-main");
```

did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The element is a dynamic element so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id$='fixedsumcredit_kp'][value='fixedsumcredit_kp']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'fixedsumcredit_kp') and @value='fixedsumcredit_kp']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I have already tried 3, 5, 7 seconds waiting.