# Selenium java clicks on the desktop view inside of ```iframe``` Element... mobile view doesn't

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is my solved question on Selenium click Element in desktop view:
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76490487/html-element-not-clickable-via-java-selenium-jsexecutor/76512397#76512397)

In mobile view I tried the same `iframe` switch, now commented out, in order to `.click()` selenium element:

```
       // utilities.desktop.Driver.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
        // utilities.desktop.Driver.getDriver().switchTo().frame(zahlungPage.oneKlarna_fixedsum_bestätigung_frameElement);

        // Thread.sleep(2000);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(zahlungPage.oneKlarna_ratenkauf_6));
        zahlungPage.oneKlarna_ratenkauf_6.click();
```

This Element does not appear in Selenium:

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='fixedsumcredit_kp']")
    public WebElement oneKlarna_ratenkauf_6;
```

present in HTML as follows:

```
<input id="-0198e3aa-d2b1-46ce-bdf0-192e60662cd3-fixedsumcredit_kp" type="radio" name="-0198e3aa-d2b1-46ce-bdf0-192e60662cd3" value="fixedsumcredit_kp" style="height: 100%; opacity: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; cursor: pointer; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">
```

error in console is this:

```
      org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //input[@value='fixedsumcredit_kp']' (tried for 10 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)
```

Anybody an idea what to try next in mobile view of the webshop in order to click the element similar to the click in desktop view?