# Selenium - the .click() command is not executed when I use Explicit Wait but when I use Thread.sleep it does

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, thread-sleep

I tried using Explicit Wait with different conditions but none works. In addition, I tried with JavascriptExecutor but here also the element was not clicked.
In the case of the code below, the element is not clicked even though the .click() command is used

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#gwt-uid-6")));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gwt-uid-6")).click();
```

And in the case of the one below with the use of Thread.sleep the .click() command is executed correctly

```
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gwt-uid-6")).click();
```

HTML Code

```
<li class="v-action" id="gwt-uid-69" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-68" tabindex="0" style=""><span class="v-icon icon-add-item"></span><span class="v-text" id="gwt-uid-68" for="gwt-uid-69">Add page</span></li>
```

What is causing this and what other way than Thread.sleep can this problem be solved?

Comment: ImplicitWait also does not work, because despite the command 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loaderBtn")).click(); the button is still not pressed and instead the code that is in the lower lines is run

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML:

```
<li class="v-action" id="gwt-uid-69" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-68" tabindex="0" style="">
    <span class="v-icon icon-add-item"></span>
    <span class="v-text" id="gwt-uid-68" for="gwt-uid-69">Add page</span>
</li>
```

The *id* attribute values like *`gwt-uid-69`*, *`gwt-uid-68`* are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

As the element is a [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html) enabled element so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.v-action[id^='gwt-uid'][aria-labelledby^='gwt-uid'] span.v-text[id^='gwt-uid'][for^='gwt-uid']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='v-action'][starts-with(@id, 'gwt-uid') and starts-with(@aria-labelledby, 'gwt-uid')]//span[@class='v-text' and text()='Add page']"))).click();
  ```