# Popup consent obstructing my selenium script from completing the test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am a newbie to selenium automation and I am trying to run this test script. Unfortunately, a cookie consent kept popping up which I believe is obstructing my script from completing. How do I perse the condition to accept the cookie in my script.

```
FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/au/request-demo/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement ddown = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
Select select = new Select(ddown); 
select.selectByValue("level1");
select.selectByVisibleText("101 - 250 employees");
select.selectByIndex(5);
```

I do not know how to instruct the script to accept or deny the cookie consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Accept All Cookies</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/au/request-demo/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sugarcrm.com/au/request-demo/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: sugarcrm.com]