# Selenium Webdriver Java Selecting an item from an Auto Suggestion Drop Down

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, autosuggest

I'm trying to select Chicago, IL from the Search City or Zip Code search box on https://weather.com/

Here's the code I've tried

```
driver.get("https://weather.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("LocationSearch_input"));
from.sendKeys("Chicago, IL");
Thread.sleep(500);
from.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
from.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
```

Any Help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's better to wait for autosuggestions to be present (they are loaded with delay) and to click on element that contains your text input.

Like:

```js
driver.get("https://weather.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
By inputLocator = new By.ById("LocationSearch_input");
wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(inputLocator));
WebElement from = driver.findElement(inputLocator);
from.click();
String city = "Chicago, IL";
from.sendKeys(city);
String cityLocator = String.format("//*[@data-testid='ctaButton' and contains(.,'%s')]", city);
wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(new By.ByXPath(cityLocator)));
driver.findElement(new By.ByXPath(cityLocator)).click();
```

Try this code, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  I did need to update the first line of code because I saw The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined error to the following                                                           WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

Comment: @zjboris I am using old version of Selenium, in `4.xx` signature of `WebDriverWait` changed, so, yep, you should use `Duration.ofSeconds`. If it works, can you mark this answer as correct, plz? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the website [National and Local Weather Radar, Daily Forecast, Hurricane and information from The Weather Channel and weather.com](https://weather.com/) the [autosuggest](/questions/tagged/autosuggest) option with text ***Chicago, IL, United States*** is a dynamic element so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://weather.com/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#LocationSearch_input"))).sendKeys("Chicago, IL");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='LocationSearch_listbox']//button[contains(., 'Chicago, IL, United States')]"))).click();
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Chicago]