# How to add an image in a text box using selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I got a text box in a website and I wish to add an image over there using selenium in python language! I have seen a stackoverflow issue where the user had solved this problem in java lang !

Referrence : [How to insert picture through selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527385/how-to-insert-picture-through-selenium-webdriver) !

(the textbox supports images as I am able to manually paste a copied image and there is also a button to upload images)

I have tried using element.sendkeys("image location path") as shown for java programme and it seems to be not working!

```
element.send_keys("assets/moon.jpg")
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the element and your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

According to the top answer found here:

[How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896685/how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java)

and here:

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/file-upload-in-selenium

You should include the absolute path to the file you would like to upload.

```
element.send_keys("full file path here")
```

From there you should be able to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("upload-button").click()
```

The idea is to send the file path and the click on the upload button.

Comment: will try it right now bro

Comment: no bro! it's not working ! it's just pasting the path into the textbox

Comment: From there you should be able to use:    

    driver.find_element_by_name("upload-button").click()

The idea is to send the file path and the click on the upload button.

Comment: Ok bro! I will try it! I have used another method to do it yesterday! it's in the answers! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

filepath = 'a.jpg'
image = Image.open(filepath)
```

I have used this instead as I was required to finish that code urgently !

and have used

```
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "V")
```